# automerge to master after deployment to Prod - how to validate before start of build if merge will lead to conflicts

Tags: git, merge

In my Jenkins pipeline, I want to be able to auto-merge (using Git Publisher) to master from my release branch after I deploy my code to the Production environment. However, before I start my build process, I want to be able to ensure that the merge will not lead to any conflict. I want to be able to perform this check in my pipeline automatically. How can I perform this check?

Git plugin from Jenkins does not allow the possibility to perform a check.